# What am I doing wrong in my Perl script written to parse a CSV file?

Tags: perl, parsing, text, csv

I have two scripts in which I'm experimenting with CSV_XS. In the first, I hard-coded everything: source directory, filename, and the csv delimiter I wanted to look for. The script works great. In the second, however, I try to dynamically discover as much as possible. That script seems to run, but it outputs nothing.

I'm having trouble figuring out why, and I was hoping you fine Perl folks wouldn't mind lending a second set of eyes to the problem:

First, the successful script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Text::CSV_XS;
my @records;
my $file = 'Data/space.txt';
my $csv=Text::CSV_XS->new({ sep_char => " " });

open(FILE,$file) || die "Couldn't open $file: $!\n";
while (<FILE>){
 $csv->parse($_);
 push(@records,[$csv->fields]);
}
close FILE;

foreach (@records){
 print $_->[0], ",", $_->[1], ",", $_->[2], ",", $_->[3], ",", $_->[4], "\n";
}
```

And second, the "failing" script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Text::CSV_XS;

$input_dir = $ARGV[0]; #I pass "Data" on the command line
my @records;

opendir(DIR, $input_dir) || die "cannot open dir $input_dir: $!";
my @filelist = grep {$_ ne '.' && $_ ne '..'} readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;

foreach $file (@filelist){
 print "Input file='",$input_dir,"/",$file,"'\n";
 if ($file =~ /comma/) {$sep=','}
    elsif ($file =~ /pipe/) {$sep='|'}
    elsif ($file =~ /space/) {$sep=' '}
    else {die "Cannot identify separator in $file: $!";}
 print "Delimiter='",$sep,"'\n";   
 open(FILE,$input_dir||"/"||$file) || die "Couldn't open $file: $!\n";
 my $csv=Text::CSV_XS->new({ sep_char => $sep });
 while (<FILE>){
  $csv->parse( $_ );
     push(@records,[$csv->fields]);
  print "File Input Line:'", $_ ,$csv->fields,"'\n";
 };
 close FILE;
}

foreach $record (@records){
 print $record->[0], ",", $record->[1], ",", $record->[2], ",", $record->[3], ",", $record->[4], "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line looks kind of suspect:

```
open(FILE,$input_dir||"/"||$file) || die "Couldn't open $file: $!\n";
```

I don't think you want to put those `||` in there. What that does is check to see if `$input_dir` is true, then if it isn't, it check to see if `"/"` is true (which it always is). Your `$input_dir` is likely always true, so you're just opening the `$input_dir`.

You should be using `File::Spec` to create your fully-qualified files:

```
my $fullfile = File::Spec->catfile( $input_dir, $file );
open( FILE, $fullfile ) || die "Couldn't open $fullfile: $!\n";
```

This will "do the right thing" in putting a `/` where appropriate (or, if you're on Windows, `\`). Then pass that in to your `open()` command.

Further, you should be using lexical filehandles and directory handles, along with the three-option `open()`:

```
open my $fh, '<', $fullfile or die "Could not open file $fullfile: $!\n";
```

Lexical filehandles are much safer, as they can't get overridden by some other module defining a `FILE` filehandle. Three-option `open()` is easier to understand and isn't prone to error when you have a filename that has a `>` or `<` or `|` in it.

If you want to get really crazy, put `use autodie;` at the top, so you don't even have to check for the return value of `open()` or `opendir()`:

```
use autodie;
open my $fh, '<', $fullfile;
```

Comment: No, open() or die() is a common idiom in Perl.  If open() fails then it returns a false value, so that is fine.  Really, using autodie or Fatal is generally considered better practice at this point though.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a common idiom. That's why I didn't say "you must use autodie", instead putting it in a "if you want to get crazy" section.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that right after I added the comment. My apologies.

Comment: All fantastic suggestions, CanSpice! Thanks so much for the help. :) One thing I'd like to add, is that I had to remember to put the lexical reference in "<" and ">". Without it, the script started gobbling up all the storage on my workstation :O